# On timeout logs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a moderation bot and I want it to log everything, I did everything but now how can I check if a member is given timeout, I searched up everything I could but didn't find anything please help me

Comment: If you've searched "everything" and didn't find "anything" then there's no solution I suppose.

Comment: I mean everything I could, now I gave up on searching and came here to ask I thought someone else will know it cause a lot of the bots have this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, you can check if a `Member` is timed out by looking at the [timed_out_until](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.timed_out_until) attribute.

So, if you want to track when a member is timed out, you can use the [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event and check if the new member it's timed out.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
    if before.timed_out_until is None:
        if after.timed_out_until is not None:
            print(f"Member {after} was timed out!")
```